# PrestaShop - Can't access Admin Panel on nginx

Tags: nginx, prestashop-1.7, nginx-config

I've tried the same installation of PrestaShop (ver 1.7.5.1) with Apache and nginx (copying the nginx installation into Apache root dir).

When I surf on admin panel I see urls like this:

http://localhost/admin825pqjv9z/index.php/configure/advanced/system-information/?_token=lJz8rH0rLWJJsrgY6tC97KuCrniEs2eps41UEoU5vqY

where index.php is concatenated with the rest of the url

When I use Apache every work fine however with Nginx, I'm getting redirected.

I've tried the following nginx configuration for PrestaShop:
https://gist.github.com/vicobits/86804fa5f6bd9e2a38f353518563590f

but it did not worked.

Answer (score 2):

I just tried the example you provided on my nginx install and it went well.

Did you replace `/admin-dev/` by your own admin folder name `/admin825pqjv9z/`? You should have:

```
location /admin825pqjv9z/ {  # Change this for your admin url
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite ^/.*$ /admin825pqjv9z/index.php last;
        }
    }
```

I hope this helps, otherwise I'd be happy to check other options with you.